# JSON.NET serialisation of nullable structs and TypeNameHandling.Auto

Tags: c#, json.net

The following program:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace JsonPlayground
{
    public class Program
    {
        private struct Message
        {
            public string Value { get; }

            [JsonConstructor]
            public Message(string value)
            {
                if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));

                Value = value;
            }
        }

        private class ObjectWithOptionalMessage
        {
            public Message? Message { get; }

            public ObjectWithOptionalMessage(Message? message)
            {
                Message = message;
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var objWithMessage = new ObjectWithOptionalMessage(new Message("Hello!"));

            var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
                Formatting = Formatting.Indented
            };

            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objWithMessage, serializerSettings));
        }
    }
}
```

Gives me the following output:

```
{
  "Message": {
    "$type": "System.Nullable`1[[JsonPlayground.Program+Message, JsonPlayground]], System.Private.CoreLib",
    "Value": "Hello!"
  }
}
```

And I can't think of a reason why `$type` should be included for what is clearly a well declared property. If I declare the `Message` property to not be nullable, the `$type` property is not included.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure why it's doing this, but a fix is to put `[JsonProperty(TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None)]` on the `Message` property.

Comment: Also you can add ignore param for null values JsonSerializerSettings.               NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore .

Comment: @DavidG Indeed, that does solve it, and it certainly is going to help but it does seem like a bug?

Comment: @AndreyBurykin sure, that would remove the property alltogether but that's going to change the shape of the outcome. It'll work too in my case but it may not be a good solution for everyone.

Comment: @DaveVandenEynde I think it isn't bug because if you work with structure it can be easily converted to json, but it's a problem to convert refence type, so it tries to save information about source type.

Comment: Not sure it's a bug. What you have is a nullable struct, in other words `Nullable<Message>`, I wonder if Json.Net is just being careful with generic types as you can usually pass in an object with a different type parameter.

Comment: But there is no ambiguity as to what the declared type is. You can't assign anything other than either `null` or a Message object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in JSON.NET, and it was reported [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1050) and fixed with [this PR](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/pull/1051).

Answer (score 1):

The comment by DavidG did the trick, so to formulate it as an answer, applying a `JsonPropertyAttribute` like so:

```
    private class ObjectWithOptionalMessage
    {
        [JsonProperty(TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None)]
        public Message? Message { get; }

        public ObjectWithOptionalMessage(Message? message)
        {
            Message = message;
        }
    }
```

Does seem to solve the problem for me.

Comment: Stealing my answer, sneaky! :)

Comment: You do it and I'll delete this answer.

Comment: I'm only kidding. I didn't put it as an answer as it doesn't really answer the question you posed, it's just a workaround.

Comment: I guess we only find out by opening an issue on the repo.

Comment: Not a bad idea, James (and other contributors) is usually pretty responsive on the repo.

Comment: And there you go, the beauty of open source! https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/pull/1051